# DataFrame Column Manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which I load from an excel file like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, 0, index_col=0, skiprows=0, parse_cols=[0, 8, 9], tz='UTC',
                   parse_dates=True)
```

I do some simple changing of the column names just for my own readability:

```
df.columns = ['Ticker', 'Price']
```

The data in the ticker column looks like:

```
AAV.
AAV.
AAV.UN
AAV.UN
```

I am trying to remove the period from the end of the letters when there is no other letters following it.

I know I could use something like:

```
df['Ticker'].str.rstrip('.')
```

But that does not work, is there some other way to do what I need? I think my issue is that method is for a series and not a column of values. I tried apply and could not seem to get that to work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use map() and a lambda like this

```
df['Ticker'] = df['Ticker'].map( lambda x : x[:-1] if x.endswith('.') else x)


    Ticker
0   AAV
1   AAV
2   AAV.UN
3   AAV.UN
```